# How to manually change the streaming video quality in AV player in ios?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer

I am building application in which online `streaming` is handled by `AV Player`(Default iOS player).

I want to add button for `HD` streaming, how to I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to ensure that the underlying `AVAsset` is ready to return basic info, such as its duration, before feeding it to the AVPlayer. AVAsset has a method `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:` which is handy for this:

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.mediaURL];
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"duration"] completionHandler:^{
    AVPlayerItem *newItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    [self.avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:newItem];
}];
```

In my case the URL is a network resource, and replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem: will actually block for several seconds waiting for this information to download otherwise.